# Plotting an algorithm with interactive figure in Python

Tags: python, numpy, plot, interactive, matplotlib-animation

I want to visualise the effect of an algorithm that takes a 2d vector as input and delivers an array of 2d vectors as output (where the array has the k-th iteration value at index k).

The way I would like this to work is by having a 2d plot of a certain range of numbers on the left that represents the input vector, and a similar 2d plot on the right that plots the connected output vectors.

For an individual input point I know I could do this with matplotlib's  `plt.subplots()` like this loosely adapted example from the documentation:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
axs[0].plot(in_x, in_y)
axs[1].plot(out_array_x, out_array_y, 'o-')
```

But what I would like to do is to move the point on the input side with the mouse and get the resulting output on the right interactively. How could this be done?